# Python and Selenium - Scrape data from multiple siblings

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

Okay so I'm new to python and of course Selenium. I'm trying to scrape a page for data and then work with that data in python and have selenium click links and store times etc...

The issue I've come across is that the page isn't formatted the way I'd like. Instead of having this...
    
        title
        link1
        link2
    
    
        title2
        link3
        link4/a>
    
I have this

```
<tr>
    <td>title<td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href>link1</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href>link2</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href>link3</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Heres the HTML I'm working with - http://pastebin.com/663T7mXc

What I'm trying to do is, get all of the links but categorise them based on the title they come under. E.g.
Title
 link 1
 link 2
title 2
 link 3
 link 4
 link 5
title 3
 link 6

and so on.

Since the links aren't children of the same  tag as the title I'm finding it's nearly impossible for me to do.

This is what I have so far

```
def test():
    print ("testing")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get("http://urlforpage.com")
    meetings = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td')
    i=0
    for meet in meetings:
        venue = meet.get_attribute("class")
        if venue == "bold":
            print "Venue: " + str(i) + " " + meet.text
            i+=1
        elif venue == "racing-insert-linked-events nextoff-inner-wrapper nextoff-scrollable-wrapper":
            print ("links")
            print venue.href


test()
```

I'm pulling the title out based on the "bold" class of the  class, my issue is, I don't know how to pull the url and link text for the links inside other  tags.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to change as little of your code as possible, is this what you're after?

```
def test():
    print ('testing')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('http://urlforpage.com')
    meetings = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td')
    for meet in meetings:
        if meet.get_attribute('class') == 'bold':
            print 'Venue: {venue}'.format(venue=meet.text)
        else:
            try:
                anchor = meet.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
                print 'link: {link}, text: {text}'.format(link = anchor.get_attribute('href'), text = anchor.text)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass  # Are you worried if something is neither a title (bold) nor contains an anchor?


test()
```